# android development - interrupt calling process

Tags: android

How can i interrupt the calling process and when identifying specific prefix, and change the calling number to my company's switchboard?

I want to call to specific numbers through my company's PBX to save money

Answer (score 0):

You'll find this [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html) on the Android developer blog about broadcast receivers useful.

You can register a receiver to process phone numbers and change them as appropriate.